# why is select column_name faster than select *?

Tags: database, b-tree

So I learned about how database queries data from the disk/ssd. by default a database queries data as a **page**. A page can be any size depends on the database, for instance postgres is 8kb, so a page can contains multiple rows lets say we got 3 rows per page. what I mean that we got the whole data in a row by default it's not just a single column. so if you query for specific column does that mean it has to filter unnessary data before returning the result while **select (*)** takes everything which means you don't have to filter for specific column you can just retreive the result directly. So I though select * should be faster than select column_name but in real world it's not and I wonder why.

PS. please do not flag this as duplicated I have read the similar questions but in my case is a bit difference.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you think returning every column to the client should be faster than just returning a single column? Filtering is done by a *where* or *join*, you already know the minimum data read from storage is a *page* regardless of how many columns are selected, so how did you arrive at that conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

When reading one column in a row-store table the pseudo code is something like

```
foreach page in table
   foreach row in page
      foreach column in selectlist
         copy column data to client
```

So the more columns requested by the client, the more work for the query to read the individual column values and send to the client.

Also if there is an index containing the column, the `select column_name` query can read the index instead of the table, possibly reducing the amount of data scanned.

Comment: I wonder why a database doesn't optimize for specific query like select * to iterate through each row only. Is there a specific reason that we could not do this

Comment: There are lots of database systems and lots of potential optimizations.  There may be something like you describe.  Every optimization forecloses other optimizations.